# UIButton text returns to original value after setting a new value to it

Tags: ios, swift

My `UIButton` is in a `UICollectionviewcell`, which is in a `UICollectionview`, which is in a `UITableViewCell`, which is in a `UITableView`.

The button is a like button, I want it to change its text when clicked. But after changing the text, it returns the original value. What might be the reason here?

Here is what it looks like:
https://gfycat.com/UnlawfulGroundedErin

This is the `onClickEvent` of button:

```
@IBAction func actionClick(sender: MyActionButton) {

    if (sender.toggle){
        print("Do dislike call here.")
        sender.toggle = false
        sender.titleLabel?.text = "Like"

    }else{
        print("Do like call here.")
        sender.toggle = true
        sender.titleLabel?.text = "Unlike"
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
@IBAction func actionClick(sender: UIButton) {
if sender.isSelected() {
    sender.selected = false
    sender.setTitle("Like", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
else {
    sender.selected = true
    sender.setTitle("Unlike", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
}
```

**Choice-2**

```
var isSelectFirst:Bool = false

 @IBAction func actionClick(sender: UIButton) {

       if isHighLighted == false{
        sender.setTitle("Unlike", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        isHighLighted = true
    }else{
         sender.setTitle("Like", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        isHighLighted = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try This. It will work properly**

@IBAction func actionClick(sender: MyActionButton) {

```
    if (sender.toggle){
        print("Do dislike call here.")
        sender.toggle = false
        sender.titleLabel?.text = "Like"
        sender.setTitle("Like", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }else{
        print("Do like call here.")
        sender.toggle = true
        sender.setTitle("Unlike", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }

}
```

UIButton have different texts for its title in different states.

**Just for your knowledge**

In `viewDidLoad:`

```
 btnObject.setTitle("Like", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
 btnObject.setTitle("Unlike", forState: UIControlState.Selected)
```

then in method `actionClick:` if you write only one statement,

```
sender.selected = !sender.selected;
```

it will work.

Comment: + for answer, this is basically what "states" for. Configure you title for states just once, then switch states

Comment: @injections thanks, right this is the correct way to use states